# MacBook Pro 16" Pinch to Zoom Delay in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, trackpad

I bought a 16" MacBook Pro a few days ago. It is on macOS Catalina 10.15.2. When I use the trackpad to pinch to zoom in Google Chrome or Chromium, for the first 1.5 cm or so, it does not zoom. It starts zooming normally after that.

I don't have Smart Zoom enabled. Pinch to zoom in Safari and other apps works fine, starts zooming instantly.

Does anyone know what might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Google Chrome has always worked like that on macOS and it's the same in many Electron apps (since they're based on Chromium).
The only thing you can do is report the bug to Google, but don't expect much.